# Extracting lines from a large text file which follows a pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, grep

How do i extract lines from a text file which satisfy this regex ^2.

I am using linux.

I know grep is able to extract the number of lines but i would need them to be output to a text file.

Is it possible to use grep or other solutions are better? The text file is about 20gb

Comment: Have you tried `grep "^2" ` *`filename`*?

Comment: with redirection : `grep ^2 filename > result.txt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is a solution. 
You have to protect with a `\` the special character `^`  in the  the expression:

```
grep -n "\^2" My2GbFile.txt  > MyOutputLog.txt
```

If you don't want the line number  write `grep` without the `-n`.

References:

- For example in [RegEx Quick References](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) you can read

> **[^...]**    Matches any single character that is not in the class. For example, [^/]* matches zero or more occurrences of any character that is not a forward-slash, such as http://. Similarly, [^0-9xyz] matches any single character that isn't a digit and isn't the letter x, y, or z.